# React router outlets migration to Nextjs 14 app router

Tags: redirect, next.js, create-react-app, router

I'm trying to migrate the starting part of `CRA` app, but I'm not sure how to do it with app router in `Next.JS 14`, because I'm using `outlets`.

Routers in `CRA` app:

```
<Route path='/' element={<HomeOutlet />}>
     <Route
       index
       element={<Navigate to={'path1'} />}
     />
     <Route path='path1' element={<AllRoutesOutlet />}>
       <Route path='path2' element={<Comp />}>
     </Route>
   </Route>
</Route>
```

I've prepared the app router, exactly as in my `CRA` app (with `layout.tsx` and `page.tsx` files), also with `children` prop, but not sure how to do the redirects. I can't use `next.config.js` redirects because there is some code that needs to be executed and `jsx` rendered from the outlets.

If I hit the `/path1/path2` directly the url, how I can execute all 3 routes as in my `CRA` app, setting up the nested structure in app router?

BR, Igor